# How to remove Horizontal Bar Chart Margins/Offset in ios charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

This is my code:

```
    productionBar.drawBordersEnabled = false
    productionBar.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    productionBar.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false

    //This was supposed to work
    productionBar.minOffset = 0.0
    productionBar.setExtraOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)

    productionBar.leftAxis.enabled = false
    productionBar.rightAxis.enabled = false
    productionBar.legend.enabled = false
    productionBar.xAxis.enabled = false
    productionBar.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    productionBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But this is what Im getting:
The grey area is the view and the colored part is the chart itself.

[image]

If I set the left/right offset to -35.0 it almost fills the view, but not for all devices.

Why I want this?

1 - I want to fill it all

2 - I want to get the maxY in size, which is productionBar.frame.size

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following lines:

```
    productionBar.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0
    productionBar.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0
```